# Why can't I do Marshal.SizeOf() for this C# struct?

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I try to call the code `int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct))` but it throws the following exception:

> Type 'MyStruct' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

My struct is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 version;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public IntPtr Start;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public IntPtr Stop;
    // And a bunch more IntPtr, all declared the same way.
}
```

The struct is supposed to be passed to C-land, where the C code will use its contents as function pointers. I can't see how computing a size would fail, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr requires the field to be a delegate type.  It will be a function pointer on the C-side after the structure is marshaled.  Using [MarshalAs] is superfluous, a delegate already gets marshaled like that.  So, roughly:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 version;
    public Action Start;
    public Func<bool> Stop;
    // etc..
}
```

Change the delegate types to match the function signature of the corresponding C function pointer.  You often have to declare your own delegate type so you can give it the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute to match the calling convention of the C function.  Usually CallingConvention.Cdecl, not the default of Stdcall.

You have to be very careful when you initialize a structure like this.  The delegate objects you create and assign to the fields must be referenced elsewhere to prevent them from getting garbage collected.  Either by storing them in a class object that's guaranteed to live as long as the C code can make calls, by storing them in a static variable or by explicitly adding a reference with GCHandle.Alloc()

Lots of ways to shoot your foot, good luck with it :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm currently populating the struct by doing `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(whatever)`. For various reasons I would like to keep the struct members as `IntPtr` - if I just remove the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]` will that be compatible?

Comment: Using GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() doesn't otherwise change anything in the answer, the exact same concerns apply.  And yes, just like declaring the field as a delegate type, you don't need [MarshalAs] on an IntPtr either.